# To what extent are errors strings guaranteed to not change?

Tags: go, error-handling

One of the main issues I have with Golang is that the error handling is basically a check for a string (I would love to be wrong, do not hesitate :))

In the example below, I am trying to create a directory, but will have different behaviour depending on the kind of issue. Specifically, if a directory exists I will just pass.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    err := os.Mkdir("test", 0644)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        if err.Error() == "mkdir test: Cannot create a file when that file already exists" {
            fmt.Printf("the dir already exists")
        } else {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}
```

It does not work, repeated attempts are not logged. Why? Ah, crap, I forgot the dot at the end of the `mkdir test: Cannot create a file when that file already exists` string.

I feel that relying on an error string is fragile, as opposed to having something like `err.ErrorType().DirectoryExists()` kind of check (which sometimes exists, in `net` for instance).

**My question: to what extent can I rely on the fact that the error strings will not change?** (in other words, that `mkdir test: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.` will not be worded differently, or ported to another national language, etc.)

I had some hope with `errors.Is()` but it ultimately relies on the string comparison.

Answer (score 6):

Go error strings don't change arbitrarily, but they also aren't covered by the [Go compatibility policy](https://golang.org/doc/go1compat#expectations): they can be changed if the increase in clarity outweighs the (inevitable) cost of breaking programs that make (fragile, unsupported) assumptions about the string contents.

The [`errors`](https://pkg.go.dev/errors) package is the robust way to check for specific types of errors.

Use `errors.Is` to check for equivalence to a canonical error (https://play.golang.org/p/co6ukgQrr58):

```golang
    err := os.Mkdir(dir, 0644)
    if errors.Is(err, os.ErrExist) {
        t.Logf("the dir already exists")
    } else if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
```

Use `errors.As` to check for a particular type of error (https://play.golang.org/p/UR1nUCRMUY6):

```golang
    err := os.Mkdir(dir, 0644)
    var pe *os.PathError
    if errors.As(err, &pe) {
        t.Logf("error creating %q: %v", pe.Path, pe.Err)
    } else if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case, you can use `os.IsExist(err)`

```
err := os.Mkdir("test", 0644)
if err != nil {
    if os.IsExist(err){
        fmt.Printf("the dir already exists")
    } else {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Good libraries should allow you to inspect errors without relying on string comparison. Various methods exist to do so:

- Comparaison with sentinel values `if err == os.EOF`
- Utility function: `os.IsExist(err)`
- Type assertion: `pathErr := err.(*os.PathError)`

There is always a way to inspect errors in the standard library without relying on strings. Check the function/package documentation for details about how to do it.

**Note:**

`errors.Is()` and `errors.As()` are a (~recent) generalisation of `==` and type assertion but for errors that could contain other errors. See https://go.dev/blog/go1.13-errors

Answer (score 0):

From https://pkg.go.dev/os#Mkdir:

> Mkdir creates a new directory with the specified name and permission bits (before umask). If there is an error, it will be of type *PathError.

This means you could type-assert the returned error to get more information.

```golang
if err != nil {
    pathErr := err.(*os.PathError)
}
```

With errors returned from functions in package `os` specifically, also take note of these two functions:

- https://pkg.go.dev/os#IsExist
- https://pkg.go.dev/os#IsNotExist

> to what extent can I rely on the fact that the error strings will not change?

To the extent which is guaranteed by the function's contract, which as in most programming languages conventionally is written in documenting comments above the function. In the case of `os.MkDir()`: you cannot.

Comment: An unchecked type assertion will cause intermittent panics https://play.golang.org/p/efjq43n6hB8. It is almost always preferred to use the `v, ok := e.(type)` assertion method to avoid panics. Or in this specific case (as you mentioned) use the `os` utility methods.